# How to write zk-snark arithmetic circuits

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, homomorphic-encryption, zero-knowledge

Paper: "Dispute-free Scalable Open Vote Network using zk-SNARKs" by Muhammad ElSheikh
Available at: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2203.03363.pdf

In this paper, the author has mentioned some pre-defined Groth16 zk-snark arithmetic circuits such as Mux(), LessThan(), GreaterThan(), etc. (page 5).

The author has also written three zk-snark circuits (page 7). This is very interesting.

But, it is not clear, how to write such programs (arithmetic circuits) and where those “pre-defined” functions were defined!

Can somebody help with how to write such programs?

Comment: You might like to check out [zokrates](https://zokrates.github.io).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [circom](https://github.com/iden3/circom).
This is a framework for writing zero-knowledge circuits in Rust. It also contains predefined circuits such as the ones you were referring to.

There are other options in general (e.g., [libsnark](https://github.com/scipr-lab/libsnark) for C++), but circom is the one the authors of the paper you refer use: see their GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/mhgharieb/zkSNARK-Open-Vote-Network), which is referred at page 2.

Comment: Thanks. I am still feeling disconnect here. This seems a different programming paradigm where normal functional programming may not fit. . Before start coding (in Circom), how to even start writing pseudocode (as in the paper) at the first place.

Comment: I imagine you are referring to the pseudocode in, e.g., page 7. Those are example of relations: they have a witness (private input), statement (public input) and "perform checks". If all the checks / assertions are passed then the relation is satisfied. 
There may be no simple answer here for how to start writing them: there is no official convention on it. Reading a few papers like the one you referred to is the only suggestion I have.